# Mapping Keycloak Realm Roles to Spring Authorities not working

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, keycloak, openid-connect

I've created a Spring Boot application in Kolin using the `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (3.0.2) and `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` (3.0.2) packages to authenticate my users using OIDC. For mapping the realm roles of my users in Keycloak (21.0.1) I've instantiated an `JwtAuthenticationConverter` that should `setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles")`. It is loaded correctly in the `OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer`, but the `GrantedAuthorities` are still set to the `scopes` and my `JwtAuthenticationConverter` lambda is not invoked.

The important part of the filter chain:

```kotlin
http.oauth2Login()
    ...
    .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
    .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()) // my fun
```

Spending a lot of time on debugging I found out that actually the `authoritiesMapper` of `OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider` is invoked and handles the mapping of the authorities. However, I'm not sure why the approach that is explained for example at [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-map-authorities-jwt) is not working for me.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2 resource server responsibilities and security requirements are too different from client ones to stand in the same security filter-chain.

Spring provides with different starters for the two for a reason:

- resource servers are generally stateless (no session) and their security relies on access tokens when clients security is based on sessions (you can't even complete an authorization-code flow without it)
- used `Authentication` implementations are not the same and the way the security-context is built / restored is completely different: from access token introspection or JWT decoding on the one side and session on the other side
- the OAuth2 flow used to get access tokens is none of resource server business. All that matters to it is if the access token is valid, how to get claims from it (introspection or JWT decoding) and to take an access decision based on those claims
- It is client responsibility to authorize requests to resource servers: set an access token as `Authorization` header. To fetch this tokens, it needs to handle OAuth2 flows (which include authorization-code and as so OAuth2 login).

As login is client business, by configuring `oauth2Login()` in a security filter-chain, it becomes a client filter-chain and what you configured below about JWTs has basically no effect (look in your browser debugging tools, you'll find session cookies but no JWT access token, even after login).

If your application is a REST API, it is a resource server. Remove `oauth2Login()`, it has nothing to do there. Use a REST client like Postman rather than your browser which, out of the box, has no idea how to authorize OAuth2 requests and send anything else than GET requests.

If your application renders UI templates on the server (Thymeleaf, JSF, ...), then it's a client and its secured with sessions. Keep `oauth2Login()` but remove `oauth2ResourceServer()` and refer to the doc for [client authorities mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities)

If your application exposes publicly both a REST API and the server-side rendered UI to manipulate it, then define two security filter-chain beans with `securityMatcher` to limit the routes the first in @Order applies to.

All that is detailed in my tutorials: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Comment: Thank you for the excellent summary! I removed the `oauth2Login` part in the `filterChain` and it works now. As I'm using GraphQL, I was quite confused by using the same Spring Boot application as client (GraphiQL) and resource server.